# How to animate an image background?

Tags: python, animation, build, kivy

So far, I have concocted code that will output an image. But when I try to animate it, I get a "build takes 2 arguments. 1 given" error.

```
import kivy 

from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.image import Image 
from kivy.animation import Animation 
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 


class TheApp(App): 

    def build(self):
        image = Image(source= "psychTREE.jpg")
        image.allow_stretch= True 
        image= TheApp.animation() 
        image.animate()
        return image 


    def animation(self, instance):
        animate = Animation(pos = (100, 100), t= "out_bounce") 
        animate += Animation(pos= (200, 100), t = "out_bounce") 
        animate &= Animation(size = (500, 500))
        animate += Animation(size = (100, 50))
        animate.start(instance)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    TheApp().run()
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to fix this code would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to animate the image so it moves side to side and up and down in the background screen.

Comment: Can you mark the code that causes the error more succinctly? Is there any part of your code which does work?

Comment: Also, are you certain that you need the &= in there? What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: I don't need the &= in there, but it's there for a transitional effect. Anyways, the part where I'm having trouble with is the 
`def build(self): 
    ###
    ### 
    image= TheApp.animation() 
    image.animate() 
    return image ` 

unbound method animation() must be called with TheApp instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

and if I add  in: 

`def build(self, animation)`
it returns: build takes two arguments. One given."

Comment: Please clarify within your question and provide the minimum code required to replicate the issue. Also please indicate your kivy version.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues:

```
image= TheApp.animation()
image.animate()
```

1. `animation` is a method of TheApp. You should call it via an instance, e.g. `self.animation()`. With your way, you're calling it as a normal function and so it does not receive the implicit `self` argument, hence the too few arguments problem.
2. `animation` expects an argument beyond just the normally-implicit self (you named this `instance`), but you do not pass one, so the function call is still invalid.
3. `animation` doesn't return anything, so even if it worked this would set `image` to `None`.
4. Neither kivy.uix.image.Image, nor None, have an `animate` method - so I don't know what you expect `image.animate()` to do.